# iOS: Swift – Can't figure out how to use indexPath in a tableView-method

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview

I am pretty new to iOS-development, I hope that you can help me.

I have a dict where the keys present the sections and the array for each key represents the rows.
I am trying to edit the cell in a way, that each cell in its section corresponds to one element of the array.

```
var contacts = [String: [Contact]]()
```

This is my dict and Contact is a custom class with attributes like firstName and lastName.

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath     indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    let keyArray = Array(contacts.keys)
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("ContactCell", forIndexPath: indexPath)
    cell.textLabel?.text = 
    return cell
}
```

I'd like to have the contact's lastName show up as the text for the cell.textLabel.

Thank you already for taking your time to help me. I appreciate this a lot.

Raph

Comment: you have an empty definition ? this will not compile !
"cell.textLabel?.text ="

Comment: The problem is that a dict has no inherent order, contrary to an array. You need to use an array of arrays, not a dict of arrays. Then you can simply access the contact with `contacts[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`section` contains an integer number. You have to create a relation between the dictionary keys and the section number for example

```
let sectionArrayKeys = ["contactsA", "contactsB"]
```

Now get the array for the section

```
let sectionKey = sectionArrayKeys[indexPath.section]
let contactSection = contacts[sectionKey]
```

and the appropriate contact for the row

```
let contact = contactSection[indexPath.row]
```

A more suitable solution – as mentioned in the comments – is a nested array

```
var contacts = [[Contact]]()
...
let contactSection = contacts[indexPath.section]
let contact = contactSection[indexPath.row]
```